# Add a row under an other row with Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, row

I wonder if there is a way to dynamically add a row under a specific other row of the table in the DOM without redefining the entire `MatTableDataSource` data.

Comment: Good Morning!  Before we can suggest how to improve the code you are currently trying to implement, Stack Overflow recommends that you try it out first, and if it doesn't work, then ask for where you went wrong.  So, please provide some code snippets and then we can try to help you out!  But to answer your question, yes, it is possible to that with the proper logic.

Comment: Can you please add more detail and code to your question? What have you tried so far? Please include snippets or a stackblitz if possible.

Comment: i am doing the stack

Comment: please add your existing code that you are trying to do

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov-aw1zqk?file=app/table-filtering-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
cloneRow(i, element) {
    ELEMENT_DATA.splice(i, 0, element);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
}
```

Comment: i don't think that there is a way to do that without redefining MatTableDataSource